# What exactly is a pumping lemma and how do you do one?

Tags: math, computation-theory

So I have a pumping lemma question `A{www|w ∈ {a,b}*}`
I have the correct answer but I'm not fully sure how it works. I'll give the answer just so people know what I'm going with

Assume A is REG
let p be the pumping length
`x ∈ A, x=a^p b, a^p b, a^p b`.... `|s|=3p+3`
where each `a^p b` is a w

Let s = xyz a split such that
1)`sum of i>=0`   `s'=xy'z ∈ A`
2)`|x|>0`   ,   3)`|xy| <=p`

By (3) y contains only a's and by (2) y contains at least 1 a.
Let s'=xyyz, Then `s=a^+ ba^p ba^p b`,

1)s' ∈ A as it contains contradiction t>p
ie. A not an element of REG

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is a math exchange for this and should be migrated there.

Comment: @Rob it's a theory of computation question, it belongs here

Comment: @Rob I don't think you can make a strong argument that this question should be moved. Math has 537 questions tagged [tag:regular-language] vs. 417 on SO, and has 17 questions tagged [tag:pumping-lemma] vs. 81 on SO. [cs.se] has similar numbers (that would be another option), but I don't see that one is clearly preferable to the other.

Comment: @beaker considering math exchange doesn't have a computation-theory tag I felt as if it belonged here. Thanks for showing the numbers though

Comment: @Jon I think your question is just fine where it is. You might add the two tags I mentioned above, it might help get your question seen by someone who can answer. Unfortunately it's been too long since I actually used the pumping lemma for me to help further.

Comment: You might want to read the answers to [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular) on http://cs.stackexchange.com. One of the advantages to {math,cs}.stackexchange.com is that you can use mathjax on those sites, making this sort of q&a a lot more readable.

Comment: I guess you tried to read up on this on e.g. Wikipedia. Where exactly did you have problem following the descriptions there?

Answer (score 1):

I do think you'd get better answers on cs.stackexchange, but here's the basic overview:

The pumping lemma (for regular languages; there's a more complicated one for context free languages) is a result about regular languages that says "if L is a regular language, then there's an integer p so that every word in L that's at least as long as p can be divided into three parts x, y, and z so that xz ∈ L, xyz ∈ L, xyyz ∈ L, xyyyz ∈ L, etc." (There are a few more details, like the length of y is at least 1 and the length of xy is <= p, so check Wikipedia for the formal statement) "p" is often called the "pumping length" of the language.

This result is usually used as a way to prove that a language is not regular - these proofs work by saying something like:

1. If L were regular, it would have a pumping length p as in the pumping lemma.
2. Construct a string that's longer than p letters that's in the language. Usually this string will end up being much longer than p letters long, but will have some part at the beginning that is p letters long to make the next step easier.
3. Show that when you "pump" this string (that is, when you repeat the part "y" some number of times) you get stuff that isn't in the language L.
4. Therefore, the pumping lemma doesn't hold for L and so L is not regular.

Note that you can't use this backwards to prove that a language is regular! You can only use this to prove that a language isn't regular, and very occasionally it can be used to prove that a regular language contains certain kinds of strings.

The example proof is following that format. Here's another proof, taken from a recent stackoverflow question:

```
L = {w ∈ {0,1}* | w has an odd length and the middle character is 0}
```

Now, proving that L is not regular:

If L were regular, it would have a pumping length p.

Consider the string s = '1'*p + '0' + '1'*p - that string is in L and longer than p characters. Therefore, by the pumping lemma s can be divided into three parts x, y, z such that |xy|<=p, |y|>0, and strings like xyyyz are in L.

But because of how s was constructed, we know that part y only contains '1' characters, do the string xyyyz only has a single '0' character, and it has more '1' characters to the left of the '0' than to the right, so xyyyz isn't in L.

Therefore, L is not regular.